# Which is faster to extract URLs in HTML? [html.parser.HTMLParser] OR [re.match] OR whatever

Tags: python

Sometimes, I want to parse HTML to extract URLs.
I find `[html.parser.HTMLParser]` and `[re.match]` both can do the job.
I want to know which is faster.

Is there a python-module like `jquery` to parse HTML?

If you have better solution, please leave a comment.

Thanks

---

lxml is very good.
it make the job really simple.

```
>>>for url in parse(urlopen('http://www.stackoverflow.com')).getroot().find_class('question-hyperlink'): print(url.get('href'))
```

Comment: `re.match` can't parse HTML. (although it may be able to extract content from HTML source)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly suggest [lxml](http://lxml.de/). In my experience, it is the fastest. lxml will actually generate a tree in memory. So you can parse/serialize/...
On the other hand, if you **have** to pick among the mentioned two options, I'd suggest you use the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module and determine it.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that `re` is faster, but the only way to know is to measure it.  Benchmark both techniques with your code and your data to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to parse (X)HTML with a regular expression has [been discussed here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Without knowing what your regular expression is, it's difficult to say. The authors that implement and maintain html.parser.HTMLParser likely spend a good amount of time optimizing it, while your choice of regular expressions can greatly affect performance. I'd just go with HTMLParser.

But if you still have something specific you want to extract and believe you can do it reliably with a regular expression, the only way to answer your question is to time both. You'll have to be careful to do it in a way that eliminates the effects of caching, etc.